# Can I use "dataLayer" code to capture "purchase" events from backend of website when batch processing orders / membership fees?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-datalayer

Is it possible to use dataLayer code on my website to capture monthly membership plan fees?  My website processes this automatically and charges my customers credit card, so would I be able to have my developer add this code so when each customer's credit card is charged this dataLayer will execute?

```
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  window.dataLayer.push({
   event: "purchase",
   ecommerce: {
    transaction_id: "{invoice_id}",
    value: {billable_amount},
    currency: "USD",
    items: [
     {
     item_id: "{invoice_id}",
     item_name: "Membership Plan Fee",
     price: {billable_amount}
     }]
    }
  });
</script>
```

Would this also work if I batch process orders on the backend of my website, where a similar dataLayer would fire for each order that is processed?

Would I need to add GTM tracking code to the admin/backend of my website for this to work?

Thank you!

Comment: There is a server-side implementation of GTM that would make this possible (https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side), but with client-side GTM is it not really feasible.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I ended up finding what I need to use to accomplish this; I guess Google calls it Measurement Protocols for sending events server-to-server. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=gtag#required_parameters

Answer (score 3):

I ended up finding what I need to use to accomplish this; I guess Google calls it Measurement Protocols for sending events server-to-server.

[Measurement Protocols - Sending Events Server to Server](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=gtag#required_parameters)

Comment: It requires "client_id" - do you just use whatever?